# Image To Stencil in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, java-17

I am new to image processing in java and I am trying to convert an image to stencil (*I think [stencil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil) is name given for it!*).

The input image is this:-

[image]

After processing the image would be like this:-

[image]

I searched google. But  could find a solution. (maybe because I don't know what is the actual name of this process.)

Is this possible with java?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @tgdavies How Sir? Is this some type of edge detection?

Comment: I guess that it's a simple threshold.

Comment: @tgdavies Sir like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48009421/17022570)?

Comment: Looks plausible, try it!

Comment: @tgdavies I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found the solution. if we Binarize an image it will work.

Input image:-

[image]

Output Image:-

[image]

Code:-

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {

 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws  IOException {
        
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\IMG_20211029_124954.jpg"));
        
      ImageIO.write(binarizeImage(bi), "png", new File("D:\\1.png"));
 
}
public static BufferedImage binarizeImage(BufferedImage img_param) 
{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
        img_param.getWidth(), 
        img_param.getHeight(),                                    
        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY
    );

    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img_param, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();

    
    return image;
}
}
```

To make the image transparent , You can do something like this:-

```
for(int i=0;i<img.width;i++){
for(int j=0;j<img.height;j++){
Color c = new Color(255,255,255,0);
if(img.getRGB==Color.white.getRGB){
img.setRGB(i,j,c.getRGB)
}
}
}
```

Comment: Wow Works great.